# Как заменить значения int64, которые равны -1000, на Nan?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Задача вроде простая, но уже третий час не могу решить ее...

Есть `.xls` файл. В нем 3 столбца с типами:

```
Column1      int64
Column2     object
Column3    float64
dtype: object
```

Я считываю файл и все значения, которые равны *-1000*, хочу заменить на `Nan`. 
Делаю это так:

```
data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='test', na_values = [-1000])
```

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, столбцы с `float64` заменяются на `Nan`, но `int64` - нет. 
Я пробовал даже при считывании файла изменять тип *Column1*

```
data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='test', na_values = [-1000], dtypes = {'Column1':np.float64})
```

Но результат не изменился.

Как в столбцах с типом `int64` заменить на `Nan` значения *-1000*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование `na_values = [-1000]` - наиболее идиоматический способ замены константного значения на `NaN`, но тут есть нюансы...

В Pandas исторически только `float*` типы данных могли содержать `NaN`, и если присвоить целочисленному столбцу одно значение `NaN`, он превратится во `float`:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [30]: df.loc[1, "a"] = np.nan

In [31]: df
Out[31]:
     a
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  3.0

In [32]: df.dtypes
Out[32]:
a    float64
dtype: object
```

В современных версиях Pandas добавили новый тип данных `pandas.core.arrays.integer.Int64Dtype` (или `"Int64"` - обратите внимание на большую первую букву), который может содержать `NaN`:

```
In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]}, dtype="Int64")

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [44]: df.dtypes
Out[44]:
a    Int64
dtype: object

In [45]: df.loc[1, "a"] = np.nan

In [46]: df
Out[46]:
     a
0    1
1  NaN
2    3

In [47]: df.dtypes
Out[47]:
a    Int64
dtype: object
```

можно использовать этот тип данных в вашем случае:

```
In [50]: pd.read_excel(filename, na_values=[-1000])
Out[50]:
   Col1    Col2
0     1    Male
1     2  Female
2 -1000    Male
3     2  Female
4 -1000  Female
5     3    Male

In [52]: pd.read_excel(filename, na_values=[-1000], dtype={"Col1":"Int64"})
Out[52]:
   Col1    Col2
0     1    Male
1     2  Female
2   NaN    Male
3     2  Female
4   NaN  Female
5     3    Male

In [53]: pd.read_excel(filename, na_values=[-1000]).dtypes
Out[53]:
Col1     int64
Col2    object
dtype: object
```